# How to use ngModel and ngClass simultaneously in Angular

Tags: angular

I am using the below code in Angular 6 with Visual Studio Code

```
<div [ngClass]="{'disabled': isReadOnly}">
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Gender" formControlName="Gender"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here `isReadOnly` is a boolean variable in typescript file

When this value of `isReadOnly` changes in the typescript file, how it should reflect in the front end?

Here I want to combine `ngClass` with `ngModel`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to disable the `<input>` when the `isReadOnly` boolean is `true`?

Comment: Yes. I want to enable or disable automatically when the `isReadOnly` variable changes in the TypeScript file.

Comment: What's the issue using both? I don't see the problem

Comment: Like this -> `<div [(ngModel)] = "isReadOnly" [ngClass]="{'disabled': isReadOnly}">` will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For applying conditional CSS classes you can implement the following,

- In your component.html file

```html
<div [ngClass]="applyStyles()">
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Gender" formControlName="Gender"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

- In your component.ts file

```js
applyStyles() {
  let styleClass = {
    'disabled': true // Additional CSS classes can be added to this object, if required.
  }
  if (this.isReadOnly) {
    return styleClass;
  }
}
```